# How to export textures?

Tags: graphics, export, geometry, textures

Is there any object geometry format for which Mathematica supports the exporting of textures for external (non-Mathematica) use ? If not does anyone know of work arounds?

All the texture primitives are culled, this is the normal behavior I see for the formats listed below:

```
g = Graphics[{Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage","Lena"}]],
        Polygon[{{1,0},{0,Sqrt[3]},{-1,0}},
    VertexTextureCoordinates->{{1,0},{0.5,1},{0,0}}]}]
Export["~/test.stl",g]
Import["~/test.stl"]
```

[image]

***I will not accept an answer that uses wolfram specific formats such as mx, wdx, etc... as this does not answer my question.***

Here are a list of the ones I have tried:

**3D Object Geometry Formats**

```
"PLY" - PLY 3D geometry format (.ply)
"OFF", "NOFF" - 3D object file formats (.off, .coff, .noff, .cnoff)
"BYU" - BYU 3D geometry format (.byu)
"OBJ" - Wavefront OBJ format (.obj)
"VTK" - Visualization Toolkit 3D format (.vtk)
```

**3D Viewing Formats**

```
"X3D" - X3D XML geometry format (.x3d)
"JVX" - JavaView format (.jvx)
"VRML" - Virtual Reality Modeling Language format (.vrml)
```

**Modeling & Rendering Formats**

```
"Maya" - Maya entity files (.ma)
"POV" - POV-Ray ray-tracing object description format (.pov)
"LWO" - LightWave 3D file format (.lwo)
"3DS" - 3D Studio format (.3ds)
"RIB" - Renderman interchange format (.rib)
```

**CAD-Related Formats**

```
"DXF" - AutoCAD 2D & 3D formats (.dxf)
"STL" - stereolithography format (.stl)
"ZPR" - Z Corp. 3D printer format (.zpr)
```

Comment: Do you know of a file type that supports embedded textures?  I only know of _Autodesk FBX_ that can contain textures in the file. However, it is particular to Autodesk.  There are other formats that are essentially ZIP files that allow textures to be transported with an object file.

Comment: Most 3D file formats support texture mapping.

Comment: 3ds, max, lwo, obj, xsi, c4d, fbx, blend, oth to name a few.

Comment: Just google "free 3d models", there are many sites that have examples: http://www.turbosquid.com/Search/3D-Models/free, http://tf3dm.com/, or my favorite: https://clara.io/library?query=starwars

Comment: @M.R. Most don't support *embedding* the texture in the file though.  Have you also checked the various packages written for interoperability with other 3D software?  There are some for POV-Ray.  Maybe some support handling textures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to export textures in 2d or 3d graphics to standard (nonmma-only) formats as of 10.3.1.

Comment: Don't know about the downvote,  perhaps you got blamed as the messenger of negative news.

Comment: Fine by me, the other answer didn't deserve any points.

Answer (score 1):

If this texture only needs to be processed in Mathematica, you can use the binary **WDX** format, which is also platform-independent and "standard" for use with Mathematica.

```
g = Graphics[{Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]], 
    Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1, 0}, {0.5, 1}, {0, 0}}]}];

Export["txtr.wdx", g]
```

Then we can import and get the exact symbol back up and running. For proof of preservation:

```
Import["txtr.wdx"]  // InputForm

(*Results in*)
Graphics[{Texture[Image[RawArray["Byte", {{{226, 137, 125},
...............
 {185, 74, 81}}}], "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", 
 Interleaving -> True]], Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{1, 0}, {0.5, 1}, {0, 0}}]}]
```

[image: lena]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no, this does not help me. By "standard" I mean non proprietary and not "Mathematica Only".

Comment: Anyone can dumpsave a symbol, this is not an answer.